# How do I organize data in a PHP search query?

Tags: php

I'm in the process of making a PHP website, where a user can input data, then search through it later, but I can't seem to organize the data :/
Heres my code:

```
<form action="uploads.php" method="GET"><input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here"><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search"></form></body></html>
```

When a user searched for their name, it results as so:

```
firstname=Mickey lastname=Mouse item1= item2= item3= item4= item5= item6=
```

Is there any way I can add a CSS or something to get the entries to line break or seperate?

Comment: where do i add that? the result was an output from a search.php that searches thru submissions.php...

Comment: @Joziah Dax DePew i have replied your doubt bro. have a look at it.

Comment: Anyhow in what ever page you may be displaying the data you have to just integrate the `<br/>` tag along with that display information.

Comment: Please attach the source code of 'uploads.php' to your post if you want help.

Comment: <?php
header("Location: / ");
$handle =

fopen("uploads.php", "a");
foreach($_GET as

$variable => $value) {
fwrite($handle,

$variable);
fwrite($handle, "=");

fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle,

"\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>

Answer (score 1):

In Your display page while displaying the data you can use the `<br>` tag so that it will display each and every data in different line.

`First Name: <?php echo $loopvariable['fname'].'<br />'; ?>`

`Last Name: <?php echo $loopvariable['lname'].'<br />'; ?>`

Like this you can provide for all the data which you print.

**Output:**

First Name: Name One

Last Name: Name Two

And you can provide as such information using the break tags in separate lines.

Comment: @u_mulder. Added the closing `?>` tag and rectified my output.

Comment: @Joziah Dax DePew. have you obtained the required solution for the question you have posted. from my answer that i have given you.

Comment: no, the display page is a .txt, changed to a .php... i have made a phishing script and modified it so that it stores user data, and instead of username and passwords, it stores store items, and a firstname and lastname. so the only display page is the .php that the users can search thru.

Comment: Ya in that search page how do you display the data over there using the php tags or via some thing else.

Comment: this is my code that lets users submit:

<?php
header("Location: / ");
$handle =

fopen("uploads.php", "a");
foreach($_GET as

$variable => $value) {
fwrite($handle,

$variable);
fwrite($handle, "=");

fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle,

"\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>

Comment: Try replacing the code that i provide now and share thoughts on this code.

Comment: <?php 
 header("Location: / "); 
 $handle = fopen("uploads.php", "a"); 
 foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) 
  { 
   fwrite($handle, $variable); 
   fwrite($handle, "="); 
   fwrite($handle, $value); 
   fwrite($handle, PHP_EOL); 
  } 
   fwrite($handle, PHP_EOL); 
   fclose($handle); 
   exit; 
   ?>

Comment: its the same exact output.

Comment: @JoziahDaxDePew. orelse in the fwrite you try the `"\n"` alone instead of PHP_EOL or `"\r\n"`.  Have a try at this

Answer (score 0):

Basically in PHP you can echo html code so you can echo `<br>` statements as in the previous answer you can also echo css and you can create a block of code that you include

```
<?php
include('SomeMoreCode.php');
?>
```

You can also echo formatting commands to create a table.  Just place the html statements in'' and join html and mysql/php values with .

```
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>date</th> <th>Home Team</th> <th></th><th></th><th>Away Team</th> <th></th>  </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['hometeam'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['fthg'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['ftag'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['awayteam'] . '</td>';
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

non mysql - php only

```
<?php

$date='19/6/16';
$hometeam='Man United';
$fthg='3';
$ftag='2';
$awayteam='Man City';

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>date</th> <th>Home Team</th> <th></th><th></th><th>Away Team</th>   </tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $date . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $hometeam . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $fthg . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $ftag . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $awayteam . '</td>';
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: theres no mySQL. its php only.

Comment: Just read your last post and now I am a bit confused you asked originally 'Is there any way I can add a CSS or something to get the entries to line break or seperate?'  I do not actually know now exactly what you are wanting.  Are you saying you want a php page that searches through a text file?

Comment: i have a php page that searches through a text file. I want; when the user presses "search", the entries that pop up to have line breaks.

Comment: OK you do not have to use sql the idea is you can combine variables and html formatting instead of mysql just use a php variables or array instead the concept is the same.  Maybe if you give an example of your data and how youn want it formatted I can help more.

Comment: as  Maarten Schermer said a sample of your data would help

Comment: If this still does not answer your question perhaps you could provide a sample text file and the search/display code

Comment: @Mr Lister - thanks for the code edit - must of been having a bad day that day - sorry to everyone for any confusion I caused